# How to center a paragraph vertically in Apache POI Java?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am currently build a word formatter tool and have some problems with Apache POI.

I am using org.apache.poi version 5.2.0

Have a look at this picture:

[image]

I need it centered both horizontally and vertically.

Currently it only centers horizontally but not vertically.

And I dont know why. Here is the code I am using:

```
for (XWPFParagraph p : docx.getParagraphs()) {
        System.out.println(p.getText());

        boolean setBold = false;
        boolean setItalic = false;
        int fontSizeToSet = 16;

        if (counter == 0) {
            p.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
            p.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
        }

        if (counter == 1) {
            p.setPageBreak(true);
        }

        List<XWPFRun> runs = p.getRuns();
        if (runs != null) {
            for (XWPFRun r : runs) {
                if (counter == 0) {
                    r.setFontSize(14);
                    r.setBold(true);
                    r.setFontFamily("Bookman Old Style");
                }
                
            }
        }

        counter++;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That's really not enough code to go on. Remember to post a [mcve] so that folks that tell you what you forgot/did wrong rather than only showing two lines that can't do anything in isolation. Also, given that there are currently four supported versions of POI, remember to say which version you're using. Give the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask) a re-read so that you're back up to speed on what SO posts should include for others to help. (or if you never read them: definitely give them a read first now)

Comment: ok thank you, i updated my post with version and relevant code

Comment: Remember that an MCVE is really about "this problem, and nothing else", not just "copying the function that you're using at the moment": there's still lots of code here that is not related to your question. A good MCVE is not a copy of the code you're using, it's a _reduction_ of the code you were using that only does that thing you're asking about, using the code you were using for just that part (including any setup that is necessary to reach that code, but as minimal a setup as possible there, too).

Comment: So in this case, it shouldn't be only part of a function, it'd be a single runnable class with a `main` and (probably) a constructor, that sets up an empty page, and tries to place the (hardcoded) single paragraph of text you're showing.

Comment: Really, thats the only relevant code. it is inside a function which gets called on a rest endpoint. the bug in my code is in code i posted, no need to overcomplicate things

Comment: Quite the opposite: the point of an MCVE is _for you_ as much as it is for us: by forcing yourself to reduce the problem to _purely_ the problem you're asking about, more often than not you end up going "oh wait, did I forget to..." and then you look something up and suddenly you solved the problem just because you forced yourself to really sit down and run through the MCVE exercise. If the question is "how do I center text", you don't need API end points, or even loading documents. You just need code that shows you creating an empty document, with a page sized appropriately, with your text.

Answer (score 3):

[XWPFParagraph.setVerticalAlignment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#setVerticalAlignment-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.TextAlignment-) is not made for vertical aligning a paragraph on the page. It sets the vertical alignment within the text line. This is similar to what `vertical-align` does in CSS. It only takes effect if the text line is higher than the single elements in that line. For example if there is text having various font sizes in one text line.

[TextAlignment](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/TextAlignment.html) has following enum constants:

`AUTO`
Specifies that all text in the parent object shall be aligned automatically when displayed.

`BASELINE`
Specifies that all text in the parent object shall be aligned to the baseline of each character when displayed.

`BOTTOM`
Specifies that all text in the parent object shall be aligned to the bottom of each character when displayed.

`CENTER`
Specifies that all text in the parent object shall be aligned to the center of each character when displayed.

`TOP`
Specifies that all text in the parent object shall be aligned to the top of each character when displayed.

The following complete code sample shows the effect of the different text alignment settings.

To vertically center a paragraph (or more)  on the page, those paragraphs must be on a single page. And there must be section properties set for this page. In section properties one then can set `VAlign` for the section above.

Unfortunately does `apche poi` not provide setting section properties up to now. So the low level `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*` classes must be used to achieve the same.

The folowing complete example also shows this. It puts a paragraph with section break next page for section above. So the first paragraph is on it's own page. Then it sets page vertical align to center for page above (section above).

```
import java.io.*;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.wp.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordParagraphAndPageAlignment {
    
 static void createSomeRichTextContent(XWPFParagraph paragraph) {
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Aligned ");
  run.setFontSize(11);
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("paragraph ");
  run.setFontSize(22);
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("having ");
  run.setFontSize(33);
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("various ");
  run.setFontSize(22);
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("font sizes");
  run.setFontSize(11);
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Default paragraph in first page, which has page vertical alignment set.");
  run.setFontSize(44);
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  //paragraph with section break next page for section above
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTSectPr ctSectPr = paragraph.getCTP().addNewPPr().addNewSectPr();
  ctSectPr.addNewType().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STSectionMark.NEXT_PAGE);
  //set page vertical align center for page above (section above)
  ctSectPr.addNewVAlign().setVal(org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STVerticalJc.CENTER);
  //page size setting (A4) for the section above
  org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTPageSz ctPageSz = ctSectPr.addNewPgSz();
  ctPageSz.setW(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(8.27d*72d*20d))); //A4 = 8.27" * 72 * 20 = Twips
  ctPageSz.setH(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(11.69d*72d*20d))); //A4 = 11.69" * 72 * 20 = Twips


  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Default paragraph");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.AUTO);
  createSomeRichTextContent(paragraph);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.BASELINE);
  createSomeRichTextContent(paragraph);
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.BOTTOM);
  createSomeRichTextContent(paragraph);

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER);
  createSomeRichTextContent(paragraph);
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  paragraph.setVerticalAlignment(TextAlignment.TOP);
  createSomeRichTextContent(paragraph);
  
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  
  // page size setting (A4) for the last section above must be at last in body
  ctSectPr = document.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
  ctPageSz = ctSectPr.addNewPgSz();
  ctPageSz.setW(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(8.27d*72d*20d))); //A4 = 8.27" * 72 * 20 = Twips
  ctPageSz.setH(java.math.BigInteger.valueOf(Math.round(11.69d*72d*20d))); //A4 = 11.69" * 72 * 20 = Twips

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./CreateWordParagraphAndPageAlignment.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: okay thank you! but i dont see which code is relevant for my problem. could you point it out to me?

Comment: Okay, it centers my title but it has a big page size now. How can I apply changes to page size again?

Comment: @IonicMan: I had not set page size for the sections. So it defaults to letter page size. I have updated my code to set A4 page size. This needs to be done for each section.